# Доступ к членам класса через .* и ->*

Tags: c++

В каких случаях используются операторы `x.*ptm` или `p->*ptm`? Прошу привести минимальный пример, где это может понадобиться. Да и вообще, где это реально может пригодится. Стоит ли использовать их? Можно ли их чем нибудь заменить?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вызывать подобным образом методы приходится ровно в том случае, если Вы сохранили указатель на этот метод :) Как это работает, описал @Harry, а вот зачем - это хороший вопрос.

Нередко возникает ситуация, когда программисты хотят упростить себе жизнь (ленивые же). Написали Вы, например, такой код:

```
#include <iostream>

enum class State {
    One, Two, Three
};

class A {
    State _cur_state;
public:
    A(State s) : _cur_state(s) {}

    void DoSomething() {
        switch (_cur_state) {
            case State::One:
                std::cout << "Foo" << std::endl;
                break;
            case State::Two:
                std::cout << "Bar" << std::endl;
                break;
            case State::Three:
                std::cout << "Baz" << std::endl;
                break;
        }    
    };
};

int main() {
    A(State::One).DoSomething();
}
```

Через некоторое время придёт осознание того, что проще-таки написать

```
class A {
    State _cur_state;
public:
    A(State s) : _cur_state(s) {}

    void DoSomething() {
        static std::unordered_map<State, std::string> state_to_string {
            { State::One, "Foo" },
            { State::Two, "Bar" },
            { State::Three, "Baz" }
        };

        std::cout << state_to_string[_cur_state] << std::endl;       
    };    
};
```

Через некоторое время оказывается, что в `case`ах должен быть какой-то замудреный код и Вы возвращаетесь к первоначальному варианту, переместив этот код в методы:

```
class A {
    State _cur_state;

    void DoFoo() { /* code */ }
    void DoBar() { /* code */ }
    void DoBaz() { /* code */ }
public:
    A(State s) : _cur_state(s) {}

    void DoSomething() {
        switch (_cur_state) {
            case State::One:
                DoFoo();
                break;
            case State::Two:
                DoBar();
                break;
            case State::Three:
                DoBaz();
                break;
        }        
    };    
};
```

Но потом Вы вспоминаете про указатели на методы и код вновь становится чистым!

```
class A {
    State _cur_state;

    void DoFoo() { /* code */ }
    void DoBar() { /* code */ }
    void DoBaz() { /* code */ }
public:
    A(State s) : _cur_state(s) {}

    void DoSomething() {
        static std::unordered_map<State, void(A::*)()> state_to_method {
            { State::One, &A::DoFoo },
            { State::Two, &A::DoBar },
            { State::Three, &A::DoBaz }
        };

        (this->*state_to_method[_cur_state])();
    };    
};
```

P.S. Обработку ошибок не писал.

P.P.S. В случае `enum`ов *быстрее* будет вариант с вектором или первоначальный, но данный пример для академических целей.

Comment: жаль только приоритет у этого оператора какой-то странный, и приходится заключать его в скобки, чтобы осуществить вызов метода

Comment: @mymedia также как и * при вызове функции по указателю, только вот * можно опустить... Оператор вызова ()  имеет один из самых высоких приоритетов

Answer (score 4):

Ну, например, у вас есть функция, которая должна вызвать определенную функцию-член определенного объекта - все определяется во время работы.

```
class Test {
    int m;
public:
    Test(int i = 0):m(i){}
    void func1() const { cout << "Test::func1, m = " << m << "\n"; }
    void func2() const { cout << "Test::func2, m = " << m << "\n"; }
};


// Тип  testfunc - указатель на функцию-член Test
typedef void (Test::*testfunc)() const;

// Вызов для объекта Test функции f
void out(const Test& t, testfunc f)
{
    (t.*f)();
}
// То же через указатель
void outPtr(const Test* t, testfunc f)
{
    (t->*f)();
}

int main() {

    Test a(1), b(2);

    out(a,&Test::func1);
    out(b,&Test::func2);

    outPtr(&a,&Test::func2);
    outPtr(&b,&Test::func1);
}
```

Рабочий пример [тут](http://ideone.com/gXJHrX).